# Python scrape table

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to programming so it's very likely my idea of doing what I'm trying to do is totally not the way to do that.

I'm trying to scrape standings table from this site - http://www.flashscore.com/hockey/finland/liiga/ - for now it would be fine if I could even scrape one column with team names, so I try to find td tags with the class "participant_name col_participant_name col_name" but the code returns empty brackets:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

def table(url):
    teams = []
    source = requests.get(url).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
    for td in soup.find_all("td"):
        team = td.find_all("participant_name col_participant_name col_name")
        teams.append(team)
        print(teams)

table("http://www.flashscore.com/hockey/finland/liiga/")
```

I tried using tr tag to retrieve whole rows, but no success either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main problem here is that you are trying to scrape a dynamically generated content using `requests`, note that there's no `participant_name col_participant_name col_name` text at all in the HTML source of the page, which means this is being generated with JavaScript by the website. For that job you should use something like [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) together with [`ChromeDriver`](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) or the driver that you find better, below is an example using both of the mentioned tools:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = "http://www.flashscore.com/hockey/finland/liiga/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

source = driver.page_source

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
elements = soup.findAll('td', {'class':"participant_name col_participant_name col_name"})
```

I think another issue with your code is the way you were trying to access the tags, if you want to match a specific `class` or any other specific attribute you can do so using a Python's dictionary as an argument of `.findAll` function.

Now we can use `elements` to find all the teams' names, try `print(elements[0])` and notice that the team's name is inside an `a` tag, we can access it using `.a.text`, so something like this:

```
teams = []
for item in elements:
    team = item.a.text
    print(team)
    teams.append(team)

print(teams)
```

`teams` now should be the desired output:

```
>>> teams
['Assat', 'Hameenlinna', 'IFK Helsinki', 'Ilves', 'Jyvaskyla', 'KalPa', 'Lukko', 'Pelicans', 'SaiPa', 'Tappara', 'TPS Turku', 'Karpat', 'KooKoo', 'Vaasan Sport', 'Jukurit']
```

`teams` could also be created using *list comprehension*:

```
teams = [item.a.text for item in elements]
```

Comment: I'm glad to help! Please remember to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) the answer if it was helpful, it's an overall good for the community.

Comment: Awesome - thank you.

I'm trying to make it work based on rows now, but rows don't have a common single class but each one has unique class instead, like this:

odd glib-participant-I9wm5xTA,
even glib-participant-zV5a4drH

And so on. Is there a way to make below line look for classes with a particular string in the name (in this case it would be "glib-participant") rather than the whole name?

     rows = soup.findAll('tr', {'class':"participant_name col_participant_name col_name"})

Comment: @SomeGuy I guess you could use a `regex` expression for that. `soup.findAll('tr', {'class':re.compile("your regex")})`

Answer (score 2):

Mr Aguiar beat me to it! I will just point out that you can do it all with selenium alone. Of course he is correct in pointing out that this is one of the many sites that loads most of its content dynamically.

You might be interested in observing that I have used an xpath expression. These often make for compact ways of saying what you want. Not too hard to read once you get used to them.

```
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
>>> driver.get('http://www.flashscore.com/hockey/finland/liiga/')
>>> items = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('.//span[@class="team_name_span"]/a[text()]')
>>> for item in items:
...     item.text
... 
'Assat'
'Hameenlinna'
'IFK Helsinki'
'Ilves'
'Jyvaskyla'
'KalPa'
'Lukko'
'Pelicans'
'SaiPa'
'Tappara'
'TPS Turku'
'Karpat'
'KooKoo'
'Vaasan Sport'
'Jukurit'
```

Comment: Great to have a solution based on `selenium` alone, +1 for *batteries included* solution!

Comment: @ViníciusAguiar: Thanks very much. I was glad to see your answer accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You're very close.

Start out being a little less ambitious, and just focus on "participant_name". Take a look at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all . I think you want something like:

```
for td in soup.find_all("td", "participant_name"):
```

Also, you must be seeing different web content than I am. After a `wget` of your URL, `grep` doesn't find "participant_name" in the text at all. You'll want to verify that your code is looking for an ID or a class that is actually present in the HTML text.

Answer (score 1):

Achieving the same using css selector which will let you make the code more readable and concise:

```
from selenium import webdriver; driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get('http://www.flashscore.com/hockey/finland/liiga/')
for player_name in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.participant_name'):
    print(player_name.text)
driver.quit()
```